# Autolink certain string, but only if it's not already linked

Tags: regex, vba

I'm trying to write a small VBA script that finds a certain string in an e-mail and create a link, but only if it's not already linked.

I tried writing a negative look behind regex, but found that VBA Regex does not support this.

Any alternatives to achieve the following? I want to select Axx, where x = a number between 0 and 9, the regex for that is: `A\d{2}`

Now I want to rule out any situation in which Axx is preceded by either a <, > or =.

Thanks.

Comment: If you know it can be only preceded by <, > or = you can use negative character class. You would need to check though if the file doesn't start with "Axx", as it won't work this way. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/KKXMth/1). Compare the result when the text starts with your keyword immediately.

Otherwise, you can match all occurences WITH the preceding sign and filter them out from whole match collection object (not sure how this would work with VBA Script).

Comment: You could [link all the strings](https://regex101.com/r/1n7CUJ/1) and then iterate [this](https://regex101.com/r/llzUrw/1) until there are matches.

Comment: I don't understand your solution horcrux. Can you show a sample in VBA maybe?